# Linux command-chkTran working in putty is not working in Java code

Tags: scripts

In Linux,via putty software,I am able to run the command 'chkTran ' from the path  '/usr/local/data/sales/workopen'.
But the same command if I try to run via the code as below,its giving error as "chkTran-command not found."
List sshResults = SshConnection.connect("cd /usr/local/data/sales/workopen;chkTran S6543FL121498");

Note:This same line of code works for the AIX (Unix) but for Linux,its saying "command not found".

Can anybody help me here please..

Comment: What OS & release are you talking about.

Answer (score 1):

In scripts, always provide the full path to executables. If the executable is present in the current directory you can do `./chkTran S6543FL121498`, where `.` denotes the current directory. Otherwise, do

```
/usr/local/data/sales/workopen/chkTran S6543FL121498
```

without the need to `cd` to the directory first.